# Is 'this.' a useful property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

couldn't find any article about it. So.. is using '**this.**Chart1..' in asp.net, c# useful? Any time savings or why and when should I use it?

Thanks

Comment: Read the C# documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really not ASP.NET-specific at all. It's just part of C#.

Some people suggest that you should *always* use it to indicate that you're referring to an instance member, as opposed to a static member or a local variable.

Personally I only use it when the qualification is *required* for disambiguation, e.g.

```
public Person(string name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

Assuming you're in a situation where it doesn't affect the *meaning* of the code (i.e. where you're not disambiguating), it will have absolutely no effect on the generated IL, so there's no performance harm or benefit.

Note that in the rare case where you want to call an extension method on the current object, you need to use `this` as well. For example:

```
public class Foo<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // Implementation omitted

    public int CountDistinct()
    {
        return this.Distinct().Count(); // this is required here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Three common uses for `this`, as per MSDN:

- To qualify members hidden by similar names.
- To pass an object as a parameter to other methods
- To declare indexers

Refer to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for examples.